# Websocket how to you actually stream data without needing to "ping" the server?

Tags: websocket, language-agnostic, streaming

I have a simple use case.Read some data from sensor and stream it to the clients.

So I choose webSocket but my problem is that I have to use some sort of a timer or an "trigger" for the server to send the data.
Right now I have a .py file that connects to the websocket and sends "ping" messages, I can move that timer to javascript and have the clients send the "ping" messages that will be better but still using an timer.

What I want is the server to stream data non-stop, to everyone that is connect.

The server must be something like:

- Client- Hey WS server I want to connect to you.
- Sv- Cool you are in.
- Client- Thanks for accep....
- Server- Here have some infinite stream of data

What I thought that could work, is that each client sends their own "id" so that the server receives the message with the client id that wants the latest data and gives him the latest data and on the client side, every time it receives the update it sends another message for update again and repeat till one of them gives up, this is instead of sending the data to all clients in a loop.

The timer is gone but I think there must be something better because looking in the dev console on some web sites that use websockets I see nothing being send from the client only the server.

Doesn't the server need an event to trigger the message or is there a way to make the server stream the data?

It looks like the websockets are event driven but then how are videos being sent real time over websockets?Does the client request update?

This a ws server that I have in python and you can see the "ping" in on_message()

I don't need actual code or implementations, is just, how are people doing this?

```
PORT = 9000
clients = []

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    print("[HTTP](MainHandler) User Connected.")
    self.render("index.html")


class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        clients.append(self)
        print('[WS] Connection was opened.%s' % (self))

    def on_message(self, message):
        print('[WS] Incoming message: %s' % (message))
        if message == "ping":
            date = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            values = [0]*8
            for i in range(8):
                values[i] = random.uniform(1.5,1.9)
                #decomentati
                #values[i] = mcp.read_adc(i)* 3.3 /1023
            #conversia se face in javscript trebuie inmulti cu referinta si impartit la 1023
            message = {
                'date': date,
                'voltage': values
            }
            for client in clients:
                client.write_message(json_encode(message))
    def on_close(self):
        clients.remove(self)
        print('[WS] Connection was closed.')


application = tornado.web.Application([
  (r'/', MainHandler),
  (r'/ping', WSHandler),
  (r'/ws', WSHandler),
  ], **settings)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
        http_server.listen(PORT)
        main_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

        print("Tornado Server started")
        main_loop.start()

    except:
        print("Exception triggered - Tornado Server stopped.")
       # GPIO.cleanup()

#End of Program
```

Comment: Did you consider a pub/sub design, where all clients "subscribe" to a stream and the server publishes data to the stream on input source events?

Comment: @Myst No, but I do now, looks like a good way to do it. thanks